# Wanting to get this border effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this border effect seen below image:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ie31.png

So what I'm trying to do is only have a border on the right which points right, with the same spacing on each.

Thanks in advance,
Julian

Comment: well that's nice but have you tried anything? I just type some keyword in google and look what I have [found](http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/)

Comment: lol...which one exactly is the border? :/

Comment: @Leo The little triangle at the right (commonly called a "breadcrumb")

Comment: If you have tried anything, please add the code to your question.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: @rvighne really? breadcrumbs? Good to know that. Thanks for clarification mate...how did I miss that after 10 years in the industry as a professional developer? lol

Comment: Hey, I tried a few things but I deleted the code sorry. I was completely lost to be honest.. Thanks for the link Drixson.

Comment: @user1457836, I have an answer.  Hold on :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include any attempt you've tried first or it looks like you didn't put in any effort yourself (though I'm sure you did).

Anyway, I was able to do as you requested with some simple CSS and jQuery.

Check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/BjMcf/3/).

Here's the rundown.
**HTML:**

```
<div class="selected">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
```

This is simple enough.  All it does is create the different DIV's with their numbers.  I named the first class "selected" so it will show up as the lighter blue color when it's started.

Here's the CSS:

```
div 
{
    float: left;  /*allows the items to be inline with each other*/
    background: #123950;  /* dark blue */
    width: 50px;   /*change this value to suit your needs*/
    color: white; 
    text-align: center;   /*centers text*/
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 8px;  /*centers text a little more since part of the div is covered by triangles*/
}

.selected{
    background: #2B6A82; /*the light blue background color*/
}

div:after /*this creates the triangle after each div. */
{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:10px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-left:10px solid #123950;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.selected:after /*this creates a light blue triangle after each selected div. */
{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-left:10px solid #2B6A82;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**And my jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) //if the current clicked div is already selected...
        {
            //...do nothing
        }
        else //otherwise,
        {
            $('div').removeClass("selected"); //remove the selected class from all divs
            $(this).addClass("selected"); //only add selected style to clicked div.
        }
});
});
```